# How to download ANDL plugin for OMNET++. I try to install new software from OMNET++, it's installing ANDL IDE by default

Tags: omnet++

For OMNET++ 5.5.1, please help me with downloading ANDL plugin.
Tried below steps.

- From Help -> Install new software -> Followed steps given in https://core-researchgroup.de/projects/simulation/
- This approach did not install ANDL plugin, instead I see ANDL IDE is been installed